# react- create my create app deploy issues weird

Tags: javascript, reactjs, deployment, create-react-app, github-pages

so I have been trying for the last 2 hours to deploy an app on github pages.
following several tutorials/// and so far as i can tell, the issue that is happening causing the 404 is
github is looking for a index.html file in the root... however the index.html file is in the public folder...

so my question is, after looking at about 12 tutorials, no one mentions any other steps other than...

make sure you have a io repo... done.
make the json file changes,

```
  "homepage": "https://altruios.github.io/colorClicker",
  "scripts": {
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d build",
    //other stuff etc...
    }
```

install gh-pages... done.

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "gh-pages": "^3.0.0"
  }
```

make sure you have a repo for the app... done.

npm run deploy .... done... it says published, with no errors or indication something went wrong.

after these steps that are repeated everywhere with little variation, I have yet to get it deployed successfully.

the altrious.github.io is online,
if I add an index to the root of the colorClicker repo github directs to that...

I don't understand what exactly I'm missing.

I have followed several tutorials, multiple times now, none of which resulted in a success, or really gave any insight to a missing step.

where am I going wrong / what am I missing.

https://github.com/altruios/colorClicker

is the repo I'm trying to get on github pages...

(this is my first time doing this, so clearly I'm missing some key knowledge somewhere)

Comment: I would suggest to start simple, without using `gh-pages` module. Here is a simple guide and basics of deploying on github-pages: https://pages.github.com . First start with deploying a *Hello World* using *index.html*, if that works, do `npm run build` and deploy the build output same way you deployed the HelloWorld. Then, to make this process easier, you may want to consider trying `gh-pages`. Note that using `gh-pages` isn't required.

Comment: I have deployed a hello world via altrious.github.io. i am able to get a hello world just fine.

Comment: https://altruios.github.io/ need the https, it works fine for me.

Comment: sorry, there was also a misspelling in my first commment :/

Comment: Yes. It is working. Now, do `npm run build` in your React repo, and after that copy / commit / push (all the files / folder inside "build") to [this](https://github.com/altruios/altruios.github.io) repo. After this your "master" branch should look like [this](https://github.com/ajeetshah/ajeetshah.github.io).

Comment: And if your master branch looks like the one I provided in above comment, Your react application would also be accessible at https://altruios.github.io , after this you may want to use `gh-pages` to make this process simpler.

Comment: I'm going to post the answer in a moment, but your comments were helpful... however did not relate to the actual issue that was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

so I finally figured it out. there was a step that one tutorial had, that most seemed to miss. is which branch is published...

[image: correct]

before I had it publishing from the master. and the GH-pages branch is the correct branch to publish from.

hopefully this helps others from tearing out their hair.